# Shall mod(s) delete the users whose profiles (photos) are not appropriate Islamically?

Tags: discussion

Occasionally it is seen that the profiles’ photos of some users are not appropriate by paying heed to Islamic doctrines, like the following link which is related to an old user which doesn’t look constructive and OK.

https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/423/blaster

What shall we (or Moderators) do about them? Should dear moderators delete them or warn them respectfully to change their photos?

On the other hand, rarely it is seen that the photos of some female users (I mean their profiles’ photos) are not Islamically. I mean for instance they paste their eyes (zoomed) or their faces which are full of make-up and attractive for non-mahrams which are not according to the doctrines of Islam. So, Shall dear moderators at least warn them respectfully to change their photos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moderators can intervene when an image is actually offensive or clearly inappropriate, but it is important to remember that we are a site for questions *about* Islam, but  **we are NOT an Islamic site**. We are open to users from the Internet at large, many (most) of which don't know or don't *care* about "Islamic" standards for profile pictures.

If you're uncomfortable seeing profile images that are against your personal beliefs (such as the one you linked; I see absolutely nothing inappropriate or offensive about it at all), you are more than capable of just disabling images entirely in your browser of choice. Pushing some sort of "dress code" for users (Muslim or not) who are most likely just going the simplest route of using the same profile image they use for *every other site on the Stack Exchange network* will likely just discourage them from even *participating*.

Comment: Firstly, I didn't say that it is a problem for me as a personal problem that you say "if you're uncomfortable...", I said Shall mod(s) ...  in order to removing... if it is a problem...  / Secondly, you convinced me by mentioning the following sentence " we are a site for questions about Islam, but we are NOT an Islamic site. " / Well done mate.