# Are profile pictures that depict people discouraged on this site?

Tags: discussion

I have to ask because I know that Islam [discourages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aniconism_in_Islam) depicting Allah, the prophets, other humans, animals, and other things. Does this policy apply here, on Islam SE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. A few people might take issue but as long as your image isn't blatantly offensive (which is pretty much policy across the SE network) we don't really worry about it.

See also: [Shall mod(s) delete the users whose profiles (photos) are not appropriate Islamically?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1615/22)